# Oracle Instant Client SQL*Loader tool doesn't start because of missing libomsodm.so

Tags: database, oracle, sql-loader

I installed oracle basic instant client v21 x64 RPM package on my ubuntu 20.04 with instant tools same version. Now I cannot run **sqlldr tool**, sqlldr: error while loading shared libraries: libomsodm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory is thrown. I tried other tools like **sqlplus** and it's OK. My envvars is set properly as described in [documentation](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html)
This is my PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH vars
[image: This is my PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH vars]
This is libraries list in lib folder and it not contains libomsodm.so
[image: This is libraries list in lib folder and it not contains libomsodm.so]
Full error message
[image: Full error message]
So my questions are why libomsodm.so not included in basic and tools packages if it is required?
Where from can I get it? (I installed all packages from [here](https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL8/oracle/instantclient21/x86_64/index.html) and there is no libomsodm)
I need lsqldr only because I have .ldr and .ctl files, which contains a backup of table data. DB stored on remote server. My last question is how to restore data from "**.ldr**" and "**.ctl**" files using linux?

Comment: Is this certified for Ubuntu?  I know the database itself is NOT certified for ubuntu, which a a completely different branch of the Linux family tree than that for which oracle was designed.

Comment: An updated tools RPM has been released on https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html with the fix for SQL*Loader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: a new 21.1 "tools" RPM package with the SQL*Loader fix is available on https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html

libomsodm.so is included in the same 21c package as SQL*Loader.  At a guess you have a mixed set of 19c and 21c Instant Client packages.

```
$ wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/211000/instantclient-tools-linux.x64-21.1.0.0.0.zip
--2020-12-16 08:52:58--  https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/211000/instantclient-tools-linux.x64-21.1.0.0.0.zip
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 104.80.236.93
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|104.80.236.93|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1167332 (1.1M) [application/zip]
Saving to: ‘instantclient-tools-linux.x64-21.1.0.0.0.zip’

instantclient-tools-linux.x64-21.1.0.0.0.zip     100%[==========================================================================================================>]   1.11M  1.12MB/s    in 1.0s    

2020-12-16 08:53:01 (1.12 MB/s) - ‘instantclient-tools-linux.x64-21.1.0.0.0.zip’ saved [1167332/1167332]

$ unzip instantclient-tools-linux.x64-21.1.0.0.0.zip
Archive:  instantclient-tools-linux.x64-21.1.0.0.0.zip
  inflating: instantclient_21_1/exp  
  inflating: instantclient_21_1/expdp  
  inflating: instantclient_21_1/imp  
  inflating: instantclient_21_1/impdp  
  inflating: instantclient_21_1/libnfsodm.so  
  inflating: instantclient_21_1/libomsodm.so  
  inflating: instantclient_21_1/libopcodm.so  
  inflating: instantclient_21_1/sqlldr  
  inflating: instantclient_21_1/TOOLS_LICENSE  
  inflating: instantclient_21_1/TOOLS_README  
  inflating: instantclient_21_1/wrc  
cjones@mac:/tmp$
```

Answer (score 2):

To complement the other two responses from Christopher Jones, in case the resolution is not completely clear:

The shared lib **libomsodm.so** is missing from the Tools Package (RPM)
**oracle-instantclient-tools-21.1.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm**, so this is indeed an Oracle bug/oversight.

Fortunately, the file is provided and present in the Tools Package (ZIP) **instantclient-tools-linux.x64-21.1.0.0.0.zip**.

So to resolve, after installing the RPM, you need to download and extract the ZIP archive, then install the missing lib as root with

```
# install -m 755 -o root -g root instantclient_21_1/libomsodm.so /usr/lib/oracle/21/client64/lib/libomsodm.so
# ldconfig
```

You should now be able to run **sqlldr** as any non-privileged user: it will display the command syntax instead of a shared library linkage fatal error.

PS: personally, I also manually create a softlink from **/usr/bin/sqlldr** pointing to **/usr/lib/oracle/21/client64/bin/sqlldr**, as this is the only tool I need in the Tools package. There's already a **/usr/bin/sqlplus** softlink created by the Sql*Plus package.

Comment: For future readers' reference, I understand the problem was not the missing libomsdom library, but the fact that it shouldn't have been required in the first place.  So don't be surprised when a future Oracle Instant Client release doesn't have this library in the ZIP or the RPM.

Answer (score 0):

I have just encountered the same issue. The existing installation of instantclient was completely purged from the system beforehand, so this isn't due to a mixup between the version 19.x and 21.1 libraries. The library file is actually missing from the .rpm package:

```
$ wget "https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/211000/oracle-instantclient-tools-21.1.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm"
...

$ rpm -qlp oracle-instantclient-tools-21.1.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm 
/usr/lib/oracle
/usr/lib/oracle/21
/usr/lib/oracle/21/client64
/usr/lib/oracle/21/client64/bin
/usr/lib/oracle/21/client64/bin/exp
/usr/lib/oracle/21/client64/bin/expdp
/usr/lib/oracle/21/client64/bin/imp
/usr/lib/oracle/21/client64/bin/impdp
/usr/lib/oracle/21/client64/bin/sqlldr
/usr/lib/oracle/21/client64/bin/wrc
/usr/lib/oracle/21/client64/lib
/usr/lib/oracle/21/client64/lib/libnfsodm.so
/usr/lib/oracle/21/client64/lib/libopcodm.so
/usr/share/oracle
/usr/share/oracle/21
/usr/share/oracle/21/client64
/usr/share/oracle/21/client64/doc
/usr/share/oracle/21/client64/doc/TOOLS_LICENSE
/usr/share/oracle/21/client64/doc/TOOLS_README
```

I normally install to Ubuntu by converting the .rpm to a .deb via `alien --scripts package.deb`. This has worked flawlessly for many years and versions of instantclient up to and including 19.10 (which I have downgraded to.) Therefore, I wonder whether this could be a bug/oversight in Oracle's packaging of the latest version.

Comment: I intended to add this as a comment on @christopherjones response, but clearly I added it as an answer instead. It's not an answer though, so sorry about that!

Comment: Noted.  And I logged Oracle bug 32422414 for this.  Thanks for reporting it